Movie in Which Main Character's Wife Has a Gambling Problem and Goes to a Japanese Banker?
So a friend of mine distinctly remembers watching an American movie a while back - had a feel-good tone along the lines of It's a Wonderful Life and was probably from around the same era (or maybe later, in the 1950s/'60s range). However, it wasn't It's a Wonderful Life. She was told that it was an American classic, but now we can't find it!
The key things that my friend remembers are that the main character's wife has a gambling problem. Because of his wife's problem, the main character is about to lose his business. So then the wife borrows money from a Japanese banker behind her husband's back to cover her gambling loss (he doesn't know anything about it). The Japanese banker then becomes the villain of the movie and goes after the main character/husband's business to get the money back. (My friend remembers finding the portrayal of this character to be particularly offensive.) She doesn't remember the ending very clearly, except that it was a feel-good "everything gets fixed" kind of thing.
Might this description ring a bell for anybody?
